# opensearchserver this directory is closed-error

Tags: search

I recently upgraded to oss1.3 rc3, and I am having some difficulties while using scheduler

9/24/12 12:49:00 PM
9/24/12 12:49:00 PM
0:00:00
Index - optimize
Optimize starts
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this Directory is closed
9/24/12 12:49:00 PM
9/24/12 12:49:00 PM
0:00:00
Web crawler - stop
Was not running

9/24/12 12:48:00 PM
9/24/12 12:48:12 PM
0:00:12
Index - optimize
Optimize starts
org.apache.lucene.store.AlreadyClosedException: this Directory is closed
9/24/12 12:38:00 PM
9/24/12 12:48:00 PM
0:10:00
Web crawler - stop
Not stopped after 10 minutes

I tried to check the log file, which looks like:

00:00:00,001 root - Cannot forcefully unlock a NativeFSLock which is held by another indexer component: /data/test/index/20120922160504/write.lock
org.apache.lucene.store.LockReleaseFailedException: Cannot forcefully unlock a NativeFSLock which is held by another indexer component: /data/test/index/20120922160504/write.lock
    at org.apache.lucene.store.NativeFSLock.release(NativeFSLockFactory.java:274)
    at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.unlock(IndexWriter.java:5739)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.index.WriterLocal.unlock(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.index.WriterLocal.close(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.index.WriterLocal.optimizeNoLock(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.index.WriterLocal.optimize(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.index.IndexSingle.optimize(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.Client.optimize(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.scheduler.task.TaskOptimizeIndex.execute(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.scheduler.TaskItem.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.scheduler.JobItem.run(Unknown Source)
    at com.jaeksoft.searchlib.scheduler.TaskManager.execute(Unknown Source)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:216)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:549)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you already fixed this issue.

The file "write.lock" is created when OpenSearchServer writes in the index. In some case (server crash, application killed), this file may not be deleted automatically.

Here is the process how to fix this:
- Stop OpensearchServer.
- Delete the file named "write.lock".
- Restart OpenSearchServer.

Sometimes, when using the scheduler, you may have concurrent jobs which will try to update the index at the same time. A typical scheduler job will do that kind of tasks:
- Stop the web crawler.
- Optimize the index.
- Replicate the index.
- Start the web crawler.

I hope this will be useful.